matlab kernel for jupyter notebook
I am trying to install matlab kernel for jupyter notebook on windows 10 and trying to run it in VS code. I have installed jupyter matlab proxy and run setup.py in the \engines folder. However when I try to run matlab code, I get this error

            Error: MATLAB Kernel for Jupyter was unable to find the notebook server from which it was spawned!

            Resolution: Please relaunch kernel from JupyterLab or Classic Jupyter Notebook.

and when I check the log file, I see warning 01:55:39.990 [warn] No nbextensions folder found for kernel.. Has anyone been able to setup matlab in jupyter notebook for VS code.
I have searched online for this and haven't found anyting relevent.
